# Requesting and outputting data with jquery/ajax/php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, return

Just started coding some Ajax and I don't know if it's too much of a basic question. Been googling around, and I just couldn't find any good answer.

But now I would like to read from a database and output the result, with Ajax.

I've got a contact list, and by clicking a name, some info about that person gets displayed in a sidebar.

How to tackle this?

Requirements:
Contactlist with all the names.
Detailslist about a selected person (name, phone, email and so on.)

simple php with ?id=15 and updating would do the trick, but since I'm developing this for an iOS web app, this would be the only solution as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

As you said its a pretty basic question. You may check the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library for developing it. There are plenty enough tutorials available, how to use it. To be short, you will be requesting with an id from the user side. From the admin side you will process the request and will echo the output, better in json format. This output will be captured from the on success part of jquery ajax. Then you will parse it (if the output is json), and add it to some dom elements.

The jQuery code will be

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
data : {id:id},
url: 'someurl/',
success : function(data){
var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
//then do further processing
}
})
```

In PHP you will be doing something like

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
if($id){
    $result = getDeatils($id)
    if($result){
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
    }
    else{
        echo "invalid";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm really familiar with PHP, but it's just the bit how I return and use data from my php function I'm unsure about.